# inheritance and calling a method(instance vs non-instance)

Tags: java, swing, object, inheritance, extend

I have this sample code below where it inherits from JFrame and thus my `add()` method is inherited from the container(`JPanel`). I would like to know the following:

1. What is the benefit of using the method directly instead of creating an object and calling an instance of the method? Do we save memory this way? I know creating an object isn't memory free so i thought maybe this is one of the benefits of extending for this particular piece of code.
2. Why do we call an instance for the following methods:

   `fc.setSize(280,125);  // width and height`

   `fc.setResizable(false);`

   `fc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

   `fc.setVisible(true);`

We inherit all of these methods so i naively tried to call them without creating objects and using them as instances but i obtained some errors complaining about non-static methods being referenced as a static context. I added them at the end of the constructor and i did not receive any problems. I would also really like to know in this case what is the benefit if any of calling an instance instead of calling the method directly. Its not like we have multiple frames so i don't see the use of creating objects.

code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FC2 extends JFrame {

    JTextField ftext, ctext;
    JButton f2c, c2f;

    public FC2(String title) {
        super(title);

        JLabel f = new JLabel("Fahrenheit");
        JLabel c = new JLabel("Celsius");

        ftext = new JTextField(5);
        ctext = new JTextField(5);
        f2c = new JButton(">>>");
        c2f = new JButton("<<<");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,10));
        add(f);
        add(f2c);
        add(c);
        add(ftext);
        add(c2f);
        add(ctext);

        ActionListener bl = new ButtonListener(this);

        // anonymous class for ActionListener parameter
        f2c.addActionListener(bl);
        c2f.addActionListener(bl);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame fc = new FC2("F2C Converter");
        fc.setSize(280,125);   // width and height
        fc.setResizable(false);
        fc.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fc.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    FC2 frame;

    public ButtonListener(FC2 frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // get at button label
        String label = e.getActionCommand();
        if (label.equals("<<<")) { // c2f
            String cstr = frame.ctext.getText();
            float c = Float.parseFloat(cstr);
            float f = c*9/5+32;
            String fstr = String.format("%4.1f", f);
            frame.ftext.setText(fstr);
        } else {
            String fstr = frame.ftext.getText();
            float f = Float.parseFloat(fstr);
            float c = (float)((f-32)*5/9.0);
            String cstr = String.format("%4.1f", c);
            frame.ctext.setText(cstr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about the differences of `static` and non-`static` methods - the methods you are inheriting are only valid in non-`static` context whilst your `main`-method is in `static` context. Don't mix these two things up!

Comment: Could you explain how creating an instance to call these methods in main make them behave so that they are valid in static context? I'm not really understanding why using instances fixes the issue.

Comment: Creating instances of objects in static contexts is like creating instances of objects in non-static contexts - only that you can not directly cross the border from static to non-static without having an object representing the non-static part.

Comment: Why though do we need to make the method static if we are accessing a method from the same class without creating an object? What is the reason behind this? I am not seeing the need or benefit from this.

Comment: The main method is static to be able to start/bootstrap your application - otherwise, the Java system program has to be able to instantiate objects and call methods to start your Java program.

I prefer to factor the main method into an own class to have a distinct program entry point which has nothing to do with the program itself but starting it from the command line.

Comment: sorry i made an edit. I meant why do we have to make the methods static if we are accessing them from the same class. Say i have class A with method B and i call method B in main(which is also in class A) without creating an object. Why is it needed for method B to be static? I'm assuming the need for it to be static is related to inheritance/polymorphism?

Comment: You simply can not call a non-static method directly from a static context. But you can instantiate objects in a static context and call methods on these instantiated objects.

Comment: Okay but i'm looking for the why behind this. Why did they make it this way?

Comment: @user2644819 It works this way because Java is an object oriented language. You should really go learn what this actually means here. Static and instance are not something you can arbitrarily choose between. They have specific meanings and are completely different things.

Comment: You misunderstood - you simply can not call a non-static method from a static context directly - only by calling a non-static method on an object you created in the static context.

Comment: After thinking about it some more i feel like this is just design issue. If you call a non-static method B from main it is directly acting on that method but if an object is created there will be an instance of method B which contradicts with the way that main was using method B, it being static, thus a design contradiction? To make sure everyone is calling method B correctly it is labeled as either static or an instance method.

Comment: But going back to my original question if those methods are inherited then we are essentially calling them from the FC2 class, the same class. Since these methods are not static then we must create an object to call an instance of the method. However in the constructor we can call them without an instance why?? They are not static so we shouldn't be able to, we should have to use an object but it works fine. How can this be?

Comment: The constructor is inherently non-static because he is the actor  responsible of setting up an object and can therefore access all non-static parts of a class. Please consult the Java basics about this, you lack some major knowledge about objects.

Comment: I know what a constructor does and how it works. What you said does not answer the question. If the method is called from the constructor without an object then what does it have to do with the constructor?

Comment: Please clarify your question - as you know, the constructor is the first called part of the newly created object and is therefore privileged to access all non-static parts of this object to initialize it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47273/discussion-between-user2644819-and-smutje)